# Get a copy of strings sent to logging

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-logging

I want to intercept the strings going to Python's `logging` framework so that I also get a copy of the strings in a list. I want this on a per function call, so the list doesn't get shared between all the calls. Kind of like:

```
def my_func():
    logging.info("some log statement")

def my_func2():
    logging.info("some other log statement")

my_func()
logs = logging.get_log()
# Gets every string that got logged in my_func()

my_func2()
logs = logging.get_log()
# Gets every string that got logged in only my_func2()
```